# Can ServiceStack run on .net core on Linux?

Tags: servicestack

The documentation about Linux hosting only mentions mono. Can the new .net core and asp.net core (DNX) also be used?

Comment: .Net Core support was recently announced:
http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ServiceStack now supports running on .NET Core from [October 20, 2016 v4.5.2 Release](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2).

Nearly all of ServiceStack’s features are now available across 21 of our most popular NuGet packages, inc. OrmLite support for SQL Server, PostgreSQL and Sqlite. We’ve been able to achieve excellent integration and code-reuse where your ServiceStack AppHost can be registered as a .NET Core module and most of your Service Implementation using ServiceStack libraries remains unchanged.

We’ve ported a number of existing Live Demos to .NET Core providing example projects so you can easily compare .NET 4.5 ServiceStack code-bases with what it looks like in .NET Core at:
https://github.com/NetCoreApps/LiveDemos

All .NET Core Live Demos are running on Linux / Docker using AWS ECS Container Service.

We’re maintaining .NET Core packages isolated from the Main NuGet packages separated with a `.Core` suffix until we’re satisfied .NET Core has been battle-tested in the wild which will enable us to make frequent releases outside of the main .NET 4.5 release cycle.

Please see the [full v4.5.2 Release Notes](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2) for details on running ServiceStack on .NET Core, its integration story and the different conventions in .NET Core.

Comment: See https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/10286952-support-dnx for more details/progress